# Full thread dump (GC threads, JNI etc...) programmatically

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have the code which generate the thread dump based on `ThreadMXBean`, but it is just the thread stats along with their stack trace, is there a way to get the other parts of the Java full thread dump generated by the `kill -SIGQUIT`?

I'm taking about the following other parts here:-

GC Threads

```
"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=3 tid=0x0000000100120000 nid=0x3 runnable
"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=3 tid=0x0000000100131000 nid=0x4 runnable
```

VM Thread

```
"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=3 tid=0x0000000101238800 nid=0x19 waiting on condition
```

JNI global references count

```
JNI global references: 1925
```

Java Heap utilization view

```
1 Heap
2 PSYoungGen      total 466944K, used 178734K [0xffffffff45c00000, 0xffffffff70800000, 0xffffffff70800000)
3 eden space 233472K, 76% used [0xffffffff45c00000,0xffffffff50ab7c50,0xffffffff54000000)
4 from space 233472K, 0% used [0xffffffff62400000,0xffffffff62400000,0xffffffff70800000)
5 to   space 233472K, 0% used [0xffffffff54000000,0xffffffff54000000,0xffffffff62400000)
6 PSOldGen        total 1400832K, used 1400831K [0xfffffffef0400000, 0xffffffff45c00000, 0xffffffff45c00000)
7 object space 1400832K, 99% used [0xfffffffef0400000,0xffffffff45bfffb8,0xffffffff45c00000)
8 PSPermGen       total 262144K, used 248475K [0xfffffffed0400000, 0xfffffffee0400000, 0xfffffffef0400000)
9 object space 262144K, 94% used [0xfffffffed0400000,0xfffffffedf6a6f08,0xfffffffee0400000)
```

My Code so far:

```
public static String threadDump() {
    String s = "";
    ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    ThreadInfo[] theadDumps = bean.dumpAllThreads(true, true);
    s += "Number threads: " + theadDumps.length + "\n";

    s += "========= Threads ===========\n";
    for (ThreadInfo threadInfo : theadDumps) {
        String t = threadInfo.toString();
        t = t.substring(0, t.indexOf("\n"));
        s += t + "\n";
        for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : threadInfo.getStackTrace()) {
            s += "   " + stackTraceElement + "\n";
        }
        s += "======\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Some of those stats aren't thread-related, you'll have to assemble them from multiple sources, not just the thread bean.

Answer (score 0):

Thread dumps generated by kill -3 gives you a dump of 'application' and 'vm' threads. The 'vm' threads you refer to and GC stats is not part of the ThreadMXBean. 
You can get the data you need for your GC stats using the GarbageCollectorMXBean. 
The only use of VM threads, that I have come across is to to identify if we are running out of memory (i.e. busy GC threads). But you can still do this with the data you get from GarbageCollectorMXBean. I have not come across the need of 'JNI global references', mainly as I've not had anything that used JNI directly.